# Wiring in spring-session without using AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer or web.xml?

Tags: spring, spring-session

So I have an existing internal application framework which only requires consuming applications to register a single filter in their web.xml - a DelegatingFilterProxy which references a CompositeFilter. As part of that CompositeFilter we have a whole slew of other filters in a specific order (some custom, springSecurityFilterChain, etc).

I now want to bring spring-session into the mix but I don't want to use the WebApplicationInitializer (I need to support servlet 2.5 containers) nor do I want to have to have every application modify their web.xml. I'd want to provide it as part of our internal framework and simply throw the springSessionRepositoryFilter into our CompositeFilter. Seems simple enough - but it seems that no matter which position I put it in (we currently have 11 or so other filters in there) things just don't seem to work. Our authentication seems to break and things just don't work. All does work fine if I do manually add the springSessionRepositoryFilter directly to web.xml - so I'm confused. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The SessionRepositoryFilter has to come before the RequestContextFilter in the filter chain. Also have to make sure to turn off disable url rewriting in Spring security, since the springSecurityFilterChain will come after the SessionRepositoryFilter. If you don't then the re-writing of the URLs with the _s parameter won't work.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same result adding multi user support to existing spring boot application secured with @EnableAuthorizationServer. Can you post your solution?

Comment: Basically create a CompositeFilter and make sure the SessionRepositoryFilter comes before the RequestContextFilter in the filter chain.

Comment: In the end I just set @Order(1) on the class with @EnableJdbcSession and @Order(2) on the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and all started to work as expected.